# Validity of header include inside extern block?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I went looking in the C++ specification for the text banning the "obviously-bogus" code below, and to my surprise, could not find any.

Am I missing something?

```
extern "C" {
#include <vector>
}
extern "C++" {
#include <stdio.h>
}
```

The closest text I could find in the C++20 spec (actually n4861.pdf) 16.5.2.2 para 3:

> A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any
> declaration or definition and, in the case of a
> module unit, only in its global-module-fragment, and shall
> include the header or import the corresponding
> header unit lexically before the first reference in that
> translation unit to any of the entities declared in that
> header. No diagnostic is required.

But as far as I can see the `extern` blocks are not listed as a declaration or definition?

This came up in the context of mixed C/C++ code bases, where due to the contingencies of using third-parties C libraries we have things like:

```
extern "C" {
#define "third-party-lib.h"
}
```

and then eventually an `#include <stdio.h>` inside the third-party library.

The real example is slightly tamer—it at least gets the language "right":

```
extern "C" {
...
#include <stdio.h>
...
}
```

But in practice even this, appears liable to go wrong, e.g., if the system C library has `#ifdef __cplusplus` blocks giving C++ specific implementations of C language features.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer thanks for the correction - I checked both the C++17 and C++20 specs, the quote is indeed from the latter.

Comment: _But as far as I can see the extern blocks are not listed as a declaration or definition?_ Grammatically, _linkage-specification_ is a production of [_declaration_](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.pre#nt:declaration). But I'm very unsure that the whole _linkage-specificaion_ in «block» form counts as a declaration.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer yeah I missed that. I must admit, I searched chapter 9 for "extern" but not linkage.
I think on a pendantic reading the whole linkage-specification is included under "declaration". If you turn that into an answer, then I'll accept it.

Comment: I can't write an answer when I'm not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
extern "C" {
#include <vector>
}
```

Is obviously a really bad idea, and might not work.  But it also might work fine, because the `vector` header file doesn't necessarily contain anything that is subject to linkage specification.  In particular, `extern "C"` has no effect on class members, so if `vector` only contains class definitions, it will not be affected by `extern "C"`.  If it contains other things (e.g. transitive #includes), your program may still work correctly if the things which `extern "C"` does affect (functions and global variables) are not needed by your program.

Still, it's a bad idea, and even if it does work on one system it may fail on another.

Comment: Possibly there are better choices of header than <vector> for the example - some C++ headers define functions outside of classes.

Comment: _it's a bad idea_ John, you are the master of understatement.

Comment: I'm adding `extern "C++" { ... }`  in my C++ headers from now  :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo - the example that triggered this, was a large mixed C/C++ code base with interdependent third party libraries & generated code. We ended up with compile errors from C++ includes C includes C-with-#ifdef-special-cases-for-C++. 
We've asked the appropriate third party vendor to fix their crap, but in the meantime, `extern"C++"` was one option considered.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - my gcc says that any template with extern"C" linkage is an error. So <vector> is probably as good an example as ever.
(Of course, a C++ implementation could use extern"C++" or just some form of pre-compiled header and therefore get the code compiling.)